# Avoid repetition in SELECT ... GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm working on MariaDB 10.3.29.

I have a query such as this one (simplified for this example):

```
SELECT
    MIN(IF(v > 0, v, v*100)) AS min,
    MAX(IF(v > 0, v, v*100)) AS max
FROM tab
WHERE someCondition = 0
GROUP BY someGroup;
```

I would like to avoid the repetition of the `IF(v > 0, v, v*100)` part, fearing it might add significant load (even if cached) for large queries. I might be wrong, maybe MariaDB is smart enough to not repeat it. In any case I'd like to avoid it, if possible.

I have tried things such as:

```
SELECT
    IF(v > 0, v, v*100) as val
    MIN(val) AS min,
    MAX(val) AS max
FROM tab
WHERE someCondition = 0
GROUP BY someGroup;
```

, but this only works if I ditch the `GROUP BY`, which I must retain in order to use [aggregate functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aggregate-functions/).
Should I use a [temporary table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#create-temporary-table), and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query optimiser is probably smart enough to only calculate this once per row. If you look at the explain plan it might indicate what it’s doing.

You could try using a CTE but the optimiser may end up running exactly the same query as your original SQL e.g.

```
with T1 as (
   SELECT
   IF(v > 0, v, v*100) as val, 
   other_columns…
   FROM tab
   WHERE someCondition = 0
)
SELECT min(val), max(val)
from T1…
```